# FreeRTOS how to change the callback function of a software timer

Tags: c, freertos, isr

I'm using the software timer API from FreeRTOS to create a timer

```
xTimer = xTimerCreate("Timer", 100, 0, (void *) 0, vTimerCallback0);
```

Is there a way to change to callback of the timer to another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is one - the software timer API is here - https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Software-Timer-API-Functions.html .  Curiously nobody has ever requested that before but I can add a function to do it easily enough - if you subscribe to check-in notifications you will see when it gets added.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it could be that the callback that you register when the timer gets created (`vTimerCallback0`) calls one from a set of other functions after some decision making in your code. It depends on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes thank you, that is sort of what I ended up doing at the end as a workaround.